# run fft(fast fourier transform in splash2 benchmark)

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04

hi i want to run fft code(following code) in Ubuntu.
for run it i installed m4 in my Ubuntu then after going to the fft directory and make i got many error?
why? anyone can help me?
and in the top of code i see some command line? what should i do with this commands?how should i use them?

here is the fft code:

```
                                                                   */
/*  Command line options:                                                */
/*                                                                       */
/*  -mM : M = even integer; 2**M total complex data points transformed.  */
/*  -pP : P = number of processors; Must be a power of 2.                */
/*  -nN : N = number of cache lines.                                     */
/*  -lL : L = Log base 2 of cache line length in bytes.                  */
/*  -s  : Print individual processor timing statistics.                  */
/*  -t  : Perform FFT and inverse FFT.  Test output by comparing the     */
/*        integral of the original data to the integral of the data      */
/*        that results from performing the FFT and inverse FFT.          */
/*  -o  : Print out complex data points.                                 */
/*  -h  : Print out command line options.                                */
/*                                                                       */
/*  Note: This version works under both the FORK and SPROC models        */
/*                                                                       */
/*************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PAGE_SIZE               4096
#define NUM_CACHE_LINES        65536 
#define LOG2_LINE_SIZE             4
#define PI                         3.1416
#define DEFAULT_M                 10
#define DEFAULT_P                  1

MAIN_ENV

#define SWAP_VALS(a,b) {double tmp; tmp=a; a=b; b=tmp;}

struct GlobalMemory {
  long id;
  LOCKDEC(idlock)
  BARDEC(start)
  long *transtimes;
  long *totaltimes;
  unsigned long starttime;
  unsigned long finishtime;
  unsigned long initdonetime;
} *Global;


long P = DEFAULT_P;
long M = DEFAULT_M;
long N;                  /* N = 2^M                                */
long rootN;              /* rootN = N^1/2                          */
double *x;              /* x is the original time-domain data     */
double *trans;          /* trans is used as scratch space         */
double *umain;          /* umain is roots of unity for 1D FFTs    */
double *umain2;         /* umain2 is entire roots of unity matrix */
long test_result = 0;
long doprint = 0;
long dostats = 0;
long transtime = 0;
long transtime2 = 0;
long avgtranstime = 0;
long avgcomptime = 0;
unsigned long transstart = 0;
unsigned long transend = 0;
long maxtotal=0;
long mintotal=0;
double maxfrac=0;
double minfrac=0;
double avgfractime=0;
long orig_num_lines = NUM_CACHE_LINES;     /* number of cache lines */
long num_cache_lines = NUM_CACHE_LINES;    /* number of cache lines */
long log2_line_size = LOG2_LINE_SIZE;
long line_size;
long rowsperproc;
double ck1;
double ck3;                        /* checksums for testing answer */
long pad_length;

void SlaveStart(void);
double TouchArray(double *x, double *scratch, double *u, double *upriv, long MyFirst, long MyLast);
double CheckSum(double *x);
void InitX(double *x);
void InitU(long N, double *u);
void InitU2(long N, double *u, long n1);
long BitReverse(long M, long k);
void FFT1D(long direction, long M, long N, double *x, double *scratch, double *upriv, double *umain2,
       long MyNum, long *l_transtime, long MyFirst, long MyLast, long pad_length, long test_result, long dostats);
void TwiddleOneCol(long direction, long n1, long j, double *u, double *x, long pad_length);
void Scale(long n1, long N, double *x);
void Transpose(long n1, double *src, double *dest, long MyNum, long MyFirst, long MyLast, long pad_length);
void CopyColumn(long n1, double *src, double *dest);
void Reverse(long N, long M, double *x);
void FFT1DOnce(long direction, long M, long N, double *u, double *x);
void PrintArray(long N, double *x);
void printerr(char *s);
long log_2(long number);

void srand48(long int seedval);
double drand48(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  long i; 
  long c;
  extern char *optarg;
  long m1;
  long factor;
  long pages;
  unsigned long start;

  CLOCK(start);

  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "p:m:n:l:stoh")) != -1) {
    switch(c) {
      case 'p': P = atoi(optarg); 
                if (P < 1) {
                  printerr("P must be >= 1\n");
                  exit(-1);
                }
                if (log_2(P) == -1) {
                  printerr("P must be a power of 2\n");
                  exit(-1);
                }
            break;  
      case 'm': M = atoi(optarg); 
                m1 = M/2;
                if (2*m1 != M) {
                  printerr("M must be even\n");
                  exit(-1);
                }
            break;  
      case 'n': num_cache_lines = atoi(optarg); 
                orig_num_lines = num_cache_lines;
                if (num_cache_lines < 1) {
                  printerr("Number of cache lines must be >= 1\n");
                  exit(-1);
                }
            break;  
      case 'l': log2_line_size = atoi(optarg); 
                if (log2_line_size < 0) {
                  printerr("Log base 2 of cache line length in bytes must be >= 0\n");
                  exit(-1);
                }
            break;  
      case 's': dostats = !dostats; 
            break;
      case 't': test_result = !test_result; 
            break;
      case 'o': doprint = !doprint; 
            break;
      case 'h': printf("Usage: FFT <options>\n\n");
                printf("options:\n");
                printf("  -mM : M = even integer; 2**M total complex data points transformed.\n");
                printf("  -pP : P = number of processors; Must be a power of 2.\n");
                printf("  -nN : N = number of cache lines.\n");
                printf("  -lL : L = Log base 2 of cache line length in bytes.\n");
                printf("  -s  : Print individual processor timing statistics.\n");
                printf("  -t  : Perform FFT and inverse FFT.  Test output by comparing the\n");
                printf("        integral of the original data to the integral of the data that\n");
                printf("        results from performing the FFT and inverse FFT.\n");
                printf("  -o  : Print out complex data points.\n");
                printf("  -h  : Print out command line options.\n\n");
                printf("Default: FFT -m%1d -p%1d -n%1d -l%1d\n",
                       DEFAULT_M,DEFAULT_P,NUM_CACHE_LINES,LOG2_LINE_SIZE);
        exit(0);
            break;
    }
  }

  MAIN_INITENV(,80000000);

  N = 1<<M;
  rootN = 1<<(M/2);
  rowsperproc = rootN/P;
  if (rowsperproc == 0) {
    printerr("Matrix not large enough. 2**(M/2) must be >= P\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  line_size = 1 << log2_line_size;
  if (line_size < 2*sizeof(double)) {
    printf("WARNING: Each element is a complex double (%ld bytes)\n",2*sizeof(double));
    printf("  => Less than one element per cache line\n");
    printf("     Computing transpose blocking factor\n");
    factor = (2*sizeof(double)) / line_size;
    num_cache_lines = orig_num_lines / factor;
  }  
  if (line_size <= 2*sizeof(double)) {
    pad_length = 1;
  } else {
    pad_length = line_size / (2*sizeof(double));
  }

  if (rowsperproc * rootN * 2 * sizeof(double) >= PAGE_SIZE) {
    pages = (2 * pad_length * sizeof(double) * rowsperproc) / PAGE_SIZE;
    if (pages * PAGE_SIZE != 2 * pad_length * sizeof(double) * rowsperproc) {
      pages ++;
    }
    pad_length = (pages * PAGE_SIZE) / (2 * sizeof(double) * rowsperproc);
  } else {
    pad_length = (PAGE_SIZE - (rowsperproc * rootN * 2 * sizeof(double))) /

                 (2 * sizeof(double) * rowsperproc);
    if (pad_length * (2 * sizeof(double) * rowsperproc) !=
        (PAGE_SIZE - (rowsperproc * rootN * 2 * sizeof(double)))) {
      printerr("Padding algorithm unsuccessful\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

  Global = (struct GlobalMemory *) G_MALLOC(sizeof(struct GlobalMemory));
  x = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*(N+rootN*pad_length)*sizeof(double)+PAGE_SIZE);
  trans = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*(N+rootN*pad_length)*sizeof(double)+PAGE_SIZE);
  umain = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*rootN*sizeof(double));  
  umain2 = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*(N+rootN*pad_length)*sizeof(double)+PAGE_SIZE);

  Global->transtimes = (long *) G_MALLOC(P*sizeof(long));  
  Global->totaltimes = (long *) G_MALLOC(P*sizeof(long));  
  if (Global == NULL) {
    printerr("Could not malloc memory for Global\n");
    exit(-1);
  } else if (x == NULL) {
    printerr("Could not malloc memory for x\n");
    exit(-1);
  } else if (trans == NULL) {
    printerr("Could not malloc memory for trans\n");
    exit(-1);
  } else if (umain == NULL) {
    printerr("Could not malloc memory for umain\n");
    exit(-1);
  } else if (umain2 == NULL) {
    printerr("Could not malloc memory for umain2\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  x = (double *) (((unsigned long) x) + PAGE_SIZE - ((unsigned long) x) % PAGE_SIZE);
  trans = (double *) (((unsigned long) trans) + PAGE_SIZE - ((unsigned long) trans) % PAGE_SIZE);
  umain2 = (double *) (((unsigned long) umain2) + PAGE_SIZE - ((unsigned long) umain2) % PAGE_SIZE);

/* In order to optimize data distribution, the data structures x, trans, 
   and umain2 have been aligned so that each begins on a page boundary. 
   This ensures that the amount of padding calculated by the program is 
   such that each processor's partition ends on a page boundary, thus 
   ensuring that all data from these structures that are needed by a 
   processor can be allocated to its local memory */

/* POSSIBLE ENHANCEMENT:  Here is where one might distribute the x,
   trans, and umain2 data structures across physically distributed 
   memories as desired.

   One way to place data is as follows:

   double *base;
   long i;

   i = ((N/P)+(rootN/P)*pad_length)*2;
   base = &(x[0]);
   for (j=0;j<P;j++) {
    Place all addresses x such that (base <= x < base+i) on node j
    base += i;
   }

   The trans and umain2 data structures can be placed in a similar manner.

   */

  printf("\n");
  printf("FFT with Blocking Transpose\n");
  printf("   %ld Complex Doubles\n",N);
  printf("   %ld Processors\n",P);
  if (num_cache_lines != orig_num_lines) {
    printf("   %ld Cache lines\n",orig_num_lines);
    printf("   %ld Cache lines for blocking transpose\n",num_cache_lines);
  } else {
    printf("   %ld Cache lines\n",num_cache_lines);
  }
  printf("   %d Byte line size\n",(1 << log2_line_size));
  printf("   %d Bytes per page\n",PAGE_SIZE);
  printf("\n");

  BARINIT(Global->start, P);
  LOCKINIT(Global->idlock);
  Global->id = 0;
  InitX(x);                  /* place random values in x */

  if (test_result) {
    ck1 = CheckSum(x);
  }
  if (doprint) {
    printf("Original data values:\n");
    PrintArray(N, x);
  }

  InitU(N,umain);               /* initialize u arrays*/
  InitU2(N,umain2,rootN);

  /* fire off P processes */

  CREATE(SlaveStart, P);
  WAIT_FOR_END(P);

  if (doprint) {
    if (test_result) {
      printf("Data values after inverse FFT:\n");
    } else {
      printf("Data values after FFT:\n");
    }
    PrintArray(N, x);
  }

  transtime = Global->transtimes[0];
  printf("\n");
  printf("                 PROCESS STATISTICS\n");
  printf("            Computation      Transpose     Transpose\n");
  printf(" Proc          Time            Time        Fraction\n");
  printf("    0        %10ld     %10ld      %8.5f\n",
         Global->totaltimes[0],Global->transtimes[0],
         ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0]);
  if (dostats) {
    transtime2 = Global->transtimes[0];
    avgtranstime = Global->transtimes[0];
    avgcomptime = Global->totaltimes[0];
    maxtotal = Global->totaltimes[0];
    mintotal = Global->totaltimes[0];
    maxfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
    minfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
    avgfractime = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
    for (i=1;i<P;i++) {
      if (Global->transtimes[i] > transtime) {
        transtime = Global->transtimes[i];
      }
      if (Global->transtimes[i] < transtime2) {
        transtime2 = Global->transtimes[i];
      }
      if (Global->totaltimes[i] > maxtotal) {
        maxtotal = Global->totaltimes[i];
      }
      if (Global->totaltimes[i] < mintotal) {
        mintotal = Global->totaltimes[i];
      }
      if (((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i] > maxfrac) {
        maxfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
      }
      if (((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i] < minfrac) {
        minfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
      }
      printf("  %3ld        %10ld     %10ld      %8.5f\n",
             i,Global->totaltimes[i],Global->transtimes[i],
             ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i]);
      avgtranstime += Global->transtimes[i];
      avgcomptime += Global->totaltimes[i];
      avgfractime += ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
    }
    printf("  Avg        %10.0f     %10.0f      %8.5f\n",
           ((double) avgcomptime)/P,((double) avgtranstime)/P,avgfractime/P);
    printf("  Max        %10ld     %10ld      %8.5f\n",
       maxtotal,transtime,maxfrac);
    printf("  Min        %10ld     %10ld      %8.5f\n",
       mintotal,transtime2,minfrac);
  }
  Global->starttime = start;
  printf("\n");
  printf("                 TIMING INFORMATION\n");
  printf("Start time                        : %16lu\n",
      Global->starttime);
  printf("Initialization finish time        : %16lu\n",
      Global->initdonetime);
  printf("Overall finish time               : %16lu\n",
      Global->finishtime);
  printf("Total time with initialization    : %16lu\n",
      Global->finishtime-Global->starttime);
  printf("Total time without initialization : %16lu\n",
      Global->finishtime-Global->initdonetime);
  printf("Overall transpose time            : %16ld\n",
         transtime);
  printf("Overall transpose fraction        : %16.5f\n",
         ((double) transtime)/(Global->finishtime-Global->initdonetime));
  printf("\n");

  if (test_result) {
    ck3 = CheckSum(x);
    printf("              INVERSE FFT TEST RESULTS\n");
    printf("Checksum difference is %.3f (%.3f, %.3f)\n",
       ck1-ck3, ck1, ck3);
    if (fabs(ck1-ck3) < 0.001) {
      printf("TEST PASSED\n");
    } else {
      printf("TEST FAILED\n");
    }
  }

  MAIN_END;
}


void SlaveStart()
{
  long i;
  long MyNum;
  double *upriv;
  long initdone; 
  long finish; 
  long l_transtime=0;
  long MyFirst; 
  long MyLast;

  LOCK(Global->idlock);
    MyNum = Global->id;
    Global->id++;
  UNLOCK(Global->idlock); 

  BARINCLUDE(Global->start);

/* POSSIBLE ENHANCEMENT:  Here is where one might pin processes to
   processors to avoid migration */

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);

  upriv = (double *) malloc(2*(rootN-1)*sizeof(double));  
  if (upriv == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Proc %ld could not malloc memory for upriv\n",MyNum);
    exit(-1);
  }
  for (i=0;i<2*(rootN-1);i++) {
    upriv[i] = umain[i];
  }   

  MyFirst = rootN*MyNum/P;
  MyLast = rootN*(MyNum+1)/P;

  TouchArray(x, trans, umain2, upriv, MyFirst, MyLast);

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);

/* POSSIBLE ENHANCEMENT:  Here is where one might reset the
   statistics that one is measuring about the parallel execution */

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(initdone);
  }

  /* perform forward FFT */
  FFT1D(1, M, N, x, trans, upriv, umain2, MyNum, &l_transtime, MyFirst, 
    MyLast, pad_length, test_result, dostats);

  /* perform backward FFT */
  if (test_result) {
    FFT1D(-1, M, N, x, trans, upriv, umain2, MyNum, &l_transtime, MyFirst, 
      MyLast, pad_length, test_result, dostats);
  }  

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(finish);
    Global->transtimes[MyNum] = l_transtime;
    Global->totaltimes[MyNum] = finish-initdone;
  }
  if (MyNum == 0) {
    Global->finishtime = finish;
    Global->initdonetime = initdone;
  }
}


double TouchArray(double *x, double *scratch, double *u, double *upriv, long MyFirst, long MyLast)
{
  long i,j,k;
  double tot = 0.0;

  /* touch my data */
  for (j=0;j<2*(rootN-1);j++) {
    tot += upriv[j];
  }   
  for (j=MyFirst; j<MyLast; j++) {
    k = j * (rootN + pad_length);
    for (i=0;i<rootN;i++) {
      tot += x[2*(k+i)] + x[2*(k+i)+1] + 
             scratch[2*(k+i)] + scratch[2*(k+i)+1] +
         u[2*(k+i)] + u[2*(k+i)+1];
    }
  }  
  return tot;
}


double CheckSum(double *x)
{
  long i,j,k;
  double cks;

  cks = 0.0;
  for (j=0; j<rootN; j++) {
    k = j * (rootN + pad_length);
    for (i=0;i<rootN;i++) {
      cks += x[2*(k+i)] + x[2*(k+i)+1];
    }
  }

  return(cks);
}


void InitX(double *x)
{
  long i,j,k;

  srand48(0);
  for (j=0; j<rootN; j++) {
    k = j * (rootN + pad_length);
    for (i=0;i<rootN;i++) {
      x[2*(k+i)] = drand48();
      x[2*(k+i)+1] = drand48();
    }
  }
}


void InitU(long N, double *u)
{
  long q; 
  long j; 
  long base; 
  long n1;

  for (q=0; 1<<q<N; q++) {  
    n1 = 1<<q;
    base = n1-1;
    for (j=0; j<n1; j++) {
      if (base+j > rootN-1) { 
    return;
      }
      u[2*(base+j)] = cos(2.0*PI*j/(2*n1));
      u[2*(base+j)+1] = -sin(2.0*PI*j/(2*n1));
    }
  }
}


void InitU2(long N, double *u, long n1)
{
  long i,j,k; 

  for (j=0; j<n1; j++) {  
    k = j*(rootN+pad_length);
    for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {  
      u[2*(k+i)] = cos(2.0*PI*i*j/(N));
      u[2*(k+i)+1] = -sin(2.0*PI*i*j/(N));
    }
  }
}


long BitReverse(long M, long k)
{
  long i; 
  long j; 
  long tmp;

  j = 0;
  tmp = k;
  for (i=0; i<M; i++) {
    j = 2*j + (tmp&0x1);
    tmp = tmp>>1;
  }
  return(j);
}


void FFT1D(long direction, long M, long N, double *x, double *scratch, double *upriv, double *umain2,
           long MyNum, long *l_transtime, long MyFirst, long MyLast, long pad_length, long test_result, long dostats)
{
  long j;
  long m1; 
  long n1;
  unsigned long clocktime1;
  unsigned long clocktime2;

  m1 = M/2;
  n1 = 1<<m1;

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(clocktime1);
  }

  /* transpose from x into scratch */
  Transpose(n1, x, scratch, MyNum, MyFirst, MyLast, pad_length);

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(clocktime2);
    *l_transtime += (clocktime2-clocktime1);
  }

  /* do n1 1D FFTs on columns */
  for (j=MyFirst; j<MyLast; j++) {
    FFT1DOnce(direction, m1, n1, upriv, &scratch[2*j*(n1+pad_length)]);
    TwiddleOneCol(direction, n1, j, umain2, &scratch[2*j*(n1+pad_length)], pad_length);
  }  

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(clocktime1);
  }
  /* transpose */
  Transpose(n1, scratch, x, MyNum, MyFirst, MyLast, pad_length);

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(clocktime2);
    *l_transtime += (clocktime2-clocktime1);
  }

  /* do n1 1D FFTs on columns again */
  for (j=MyFirst; j<MyLast; j++) {
    FFT1DOnce(direction, m1, n1, upriv, &x[2*j*(n1+pad_length)]);
    if (direction == -1)
      Scale(n1, N, &x[2*j*(n1+pad_length)]);
  }

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(clocktime1);
  }

  /* transpose back */
  Transpose(n1, x, scratch, MyNum, MyFirst, MyLast, pad_length);

  if ((MyNum == 0) || (dostats)) {
    CLOCK(clocktime2);
    *l_transtime += (clocktime2-clocktime1);
  }

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);

  /* copy columns from scratch to x */
  if ((test_result) || (doprint)) {  
    for (j=MyFirst; j<MyLast; j++) {
      CopyColumn(n1, &scratch[2*j*(n1+pad_length)], &x[2*j*(n1+pad_length)]); 
    }  
  }  

  BARRIER(Global->start, P);
}


void TwiddleOneCol(long direction, long n1, long j, double *u, double *x, long pad_length)
{
  long i;
  double omega_r; 
  double omega_c; 
  double x_r; 
  double x_c;

  for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
    omega_r = u[2*(j*(n1+pad_length)+i)];
    omega_c = direction*u[2*(j*(n1+pad_length)+i)+1];  
    x_r = x[2*i]; 
    x_c = x[2*i+1];
    x[2*i] = omega_r*x_r - omega_c*x_c;
    x[2*i+1] = omega_r*x_c + omega_c*x_r;
  }
}


void Scale(long n1, long N, double *x)
{
  long i;

  for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
    x[2*i] /= N;
    x[2*i+1] /= N;
  }
}


void Transpose(long n1, double *src, double *dest, long MyNum, long MyFirst, long MyLast, long pad_length)
{
  long i; 
  long j; 
  long k; 
  long l; 
  long m;
  long blksize;
  long numblks;
  long firstfirst;
  long h_off;
  long v_off;
  long v;
  long h;
  long n1p;
  long row_count;

  blksize = MyLast-MyFirst;
  numblks = (2*blksize)/num_cache_lines;
  if (numblks * num_cache_lines != 2 * blksize) {
    numblks ++;
  }
  blksize = blksize / numblks;
  firstfirst = MyFirst;
  row_count = n1/P;
  n1p = n1+pad_length;
  for (l=MyNum+1;l<P;l++) {
    v_off = l*row_count;
    for (k=0; k<numblks; k++) {
      h_off = firstfirst;
      for (m=0; m<numblks; m++) {
        for (i=0; i<blksize; i++) {
      v = v_off + i;
          for (j=0; j<blksize; j++) {
        h = h_off + j;
            dest[2*(h*n1p+v)] = src[2*(v*n1p+h)];
            dest[2*(h*n1p+v)+1] = src[2*(v*n1p+h)+1];
          }
        }
    h_off += blksize;
      }
      v_off+=blksize;
    }
  }

  for (l=0;l<MyNum;l++) {
    v_off = l*row_count;
    for (k=0; k<numblks; k++) {
      h_off = firstfirst;
      for (m=0; m<numblks; m++) {
        for (i=0; i<blksize; i++) {
      v = v_off + i;
          for (j=0; j<blksize; j++) {
            h = h_off + j;
            dest[2*(h*n1p+v)] = src[2*(v*n1p+h)];
            dest[2*(h*n1p+v)+1] = src[2*(v*n1p+h)+1];
          }
        }
    h_off += blksize;
      }
      v_off+=blksize;
    }
  }

  v_off = MyNum*row_count;
  for (k=0; k<numblks; k++) {
    h_off = firstfirst;
    for (m=0; m<numblks; m++) {
      for (i=0; i<blksize; i++) {
        v = v_off + i;
        for (j=0; j<blksize; j++) {
          h = h_off + j;
          dest[2*(h*n1p+v)] = src[2*(v*n1p+h)];
          dest[2*(h*n1p+v)+1] = src[2*(v*n1p+h)+1];
    }
      }
      h_off += blksize;
    }
    v_off+=blksize;
  }
}


void CopyColumn(long n1, double *src, double *dest)
{
  long i;

  for (i=0; i<n1; i++) {
    dest[2*i] = src[2*i];
    dest[2*i+1] = src[2*i+1];
  }
}


void Reverse(long N, long M, double *x)
{
  long j, k;

  for (k=0; k<N; k++) {
    j = BitReverse(M, k);
    if (j > k) {
      SWAP_VALS(x[2*j], x[2*k]);
      SWAP_VALS(x[2*j+1], x[2*k+1]);
    }
  }
}


void FFT1DOnce(long direction, long M, long N, double *u, double *x)
{
  long j; 
  long k; 
  long q; 
  long L; 
  long r; 
  long Lstar;
  double *u1; 
  double *x1; 
  double *x2;
  double omega_r; 
  double omega_c; 
  double tau_r; 
  double tau_c; 
  double x_r; 
  double x_c;

  Reverse(N, M, x);

  for (q=1; q<=M; q++) {
    L = 1<<q; r = N/L; Lstar = L/2;
    u1 = &u[2*(Lstar-1)];
    for (k=0; k<r; k++) {
      x1 = &x[2*(k*L)];
      x2 = &x[2*(k*L+Lstar)];
      for (j=0; j<Lstar; j++) {
    omega_r = u1[2*j]; 
        omega_c = direction*u1[2*j+1];
    x_r = x2[2*j]; 
        x_c = x2[2*j+1];
    tau_r = omega_r*x_r - omega_c*x_c;
    tau_c = omega_r*x_c + omega_c*x_r;
    x_r = x1[2*j]; 
        x_c = x1[2*j+1];
    x2[2*j] = x_r - tau_r;
    x2[2*j+1] = x_c - tau_c;
    x1[2*j] = x_r + tau_r;
    x1[2*j+1] = x_c + tau_c;
      }
    }
  }
}


void PrintArray(long N, double *x)
{
  long i, j, k;

  for (i=0; i<rootN; i++) {
    k = i*(rootN+pad_length);
    for (j=0; j<rootN; j++) {
      printf(" %4.2f %4.2f", x[2*(k+j)], x[2*(k+j)+1]);
      if (i*rootN+j != N-1) {
        printf(",");
      }
      if ((i*rootN+j+1) % 8 == 0) {
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("\n");
}


void printerr(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: %s\n",s);
}


long log_2(long number)
{
  long cumulative = 1, out = 0, done = 0;

  while ((cumulative < number) && (!done) && (out < 50)) {
    if (cumulative == number) {
      done = 1;
    } else {
      cumulative = cumulative * 2;
      out ++;
    }
  }

  if (cumulative == number) {
    return(out);
  } else {
    return(-1);
  }
}
```

These are some of the errors I get:

```
fft.C: In function ‘FFT1D’:
fft.C:603:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:623:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:643:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:657:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:666:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C: In function ‘main’:
fft.C:416:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
../../Makefile.config:30: recipe for target 'fft.o' failed
make: *** [fft.o] Error 1
```

Comment: What were the errors you got?

Comment: can u help me? please :(

Comment: Can you post all of the errors? One error further up may potentially cause the rest of the ones you posted.

Comment: yes you are right,excuse me

Answer (score 0):

~/Desktop/splash2/codes/kernels/fft$ make

```
gcc -c -O3 -pthread -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -Wall -W -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpadded -Winline -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-compare -Wendif-labels fft.c
fft.C:59:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
 struct GlobalMemory {
 ^
fft.C: In function ‘main’:
fft.C:134:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘CLOCK’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   CLOCK(start);
   ^
fft.C:136:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getopt’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "p:m:n:l:stoh")) != -1) {
   ^
fft.C:138:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atoi’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       case 'p': P = atoi(optarg); 
       ^
fft.C:141:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                   exit(-1);
                   ^
fft.C:141:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
fft.C:145:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
                   exit(-1);
                   ^
fft.C:152:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
                   exit(-1);
                   ^
fft.C:159:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
                   exit(-1);
                   ^
fft.C:165:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
                   exit(-1);
                   ^
fft.C:188:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
   exit(0);
   ^
fft.C:193:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘MAIN_INITENV’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   MAIN_INITENV(,80000000);
   ^
fft.C:193:16: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
   MAIN_INITENV(,80000000);
                ^
fft.C:200:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:204:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (line_size < 2*sizeof(double)) {
                 ^
fft.C:211:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
   if (line_size <= 2*sizeof(double)) {
                 ^
fft.C:219:27: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     if (pages * PAGE_SIZE != 2 * pad_length * sizeof(double) * rowsperproc) {
                           ^
fft.C:230:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
       exit(-1);
       ^
fft.C:234:20: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘G_MALLOC’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   Global = (struct GlobalMemory *) G_MALLOC(sizeof(struct GlobalMemory));
                    ^
fft.C:234:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   Global = (struct GlobalMemory *) G_MALLOC(sizeof(struct GlobalMemory));
            ^
fft.C:235:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   x = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*(N+rootN*pad_length)*sizeof(double)+PAGE_SIZE);
       ^
fft.C:236:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   trans = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*(N+rootN*pad_length)*sizeof(double)+PAGE_SIZE);
           ^
fft.C:237:11: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   umain = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*rootN*sizeof(double));  
           ^
fft.C:238:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   umain2 = (double *) G_MALLOC(2*(N+rootN*pad_length)*sizeof(double)+PAGE_SIZE);
            ^
fft.C:240:9: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
   Global->transtimes = (long *) G_MALLOC(P*sizeof(long));  
         ^
fft.C:240:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   Global->transtimes = (long *) G_MALLOC(P*sizeof(long));  
                        ^
fft.C:241:9: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
   Global->totaltimes = (long *) G_MALLOC(P*sizeof(long));  
         ^
fft.C:241:24: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   Global->totaltimes = (long *) G_MALLOC(P*sizeof(long));  
                        ^
fft.C:244:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:247:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:250:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:253:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:256:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:304:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘BARINIT’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   BARINIT(Global->start, P);
   ^
fft.C:304:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARINIT(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:305:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘LOCKINIT’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   LOCKINIT(Global->idlock);
   ^
fft.C:305:18: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘idlock’
   LOCKINIT(Global->idlock);
                  ^
fft.C:306:9: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘id’
   Global->id = 0;
         ^
fft.C:322:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘CREATE’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   CREATE(SlaveStart, P);
   ^
fft.C:323:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘WAIT_FOR_END’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   WAIT_FOR_END(P);
   ^
fft.C:334:21: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
   transtime = Global->transtimes[0];
                     ^
fft.C:340:16: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
          Global->totaltimes[0],Global->transtimes[0],
                ^
fft.C:340:38: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
          Global->totaltimes[0],Global->transtimes[0],
                                      ^
fft.C:341:25: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
          ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0]);
                         ^
fft.C:341:48: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
          ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0]);
                                                ^
fft.C:343:24: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
     transtime2 = Global->transtimes[0];
                        ^
fft.C:344:26: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
     avgtranstime = Global->transtimes[0];
                          ^
fft.C:345:25: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     avgcomptime = Global->totaltimes[0];
                         ^
fft.C:346:22: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     maxtotal = Global->totaltimes[0];
                      ^
fft.C:347:22: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     mintotal = Global->totaltimes[0];
                      ^
fft.C:348:30: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
     maxfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
                              ^
fft.C:348:53: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     maxfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
                                                     ^
fft.C:349:30: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
     minfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
                              ^
fft.C:349:53: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     minfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
                                                     ^
fft.C:350:34: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
     avgfractime = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
                                  ^
fft.C:350:57: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     avgfractime = ((double)Global->transtimes[0])/Global->totaltimes[0];
                                                         ^
fft.C:352:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
       if (Global->transtimes[i] > transtime) {
                 ^
fft.C:353:27: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
         transtime = Global->transtimes[i];
                           ^
fft.C:355:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
       if (Global->transtimes[i] < transtime2) {
                 ^
fft.C:356:28: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
         transtime2 = Global->transtimes[i];
                            ^
fft.C:358:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
       if (Global->totaltimes[i] > maxtotal) {
                 ^
fft.C:359:26: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
         maxtotal = Global->totaltimes[i];
                          ^
fft.C:361:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
       if (Global->totaltimes[i] < mintotal) {
                 ^
fft.C:362:26: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
         mintotal = Global->totaltimes[i];
                          ^
fft.C:364:26: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
       if (((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i] > maxfrac) {
                          ^
fft.C:364:49: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
       if (((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i] > maxfrac) {
                                                 ^
fft.C:365:34: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
         maxfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
                                  ^
fft.C:365:57: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
         maxfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
                                                         ^
fft.C:367:26: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
       if (((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i] < minfrac) {
                          ^
fft.C:367:49: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
       if (((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i] < minfrac) {
                                                 ^
fft.C:368:34: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
         minfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
                                  ^
fft.C:368:57: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
         minfrac = ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
                                                         ^
fft.C:371:22: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
              i,Global->totaltimes[i],Global->transtimes[i],
                      ^
fft.C:371:44: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
              i,Global->totaltimes[i],Global->transtimes[i],
                                            ^
fft.C:372:29: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
              ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i]);
                             ^
fft.C:372:52: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
              ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i]);
                                                    ^
fft.C:373:29: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
       avgtranstime += Global->transtimes[i];
                             ^
fft.C:374:28: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
       avgcomptime += Global->totaltimes[i];
                            ^
fft.C:375:37: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
       avgfractime += ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
                                     ^
fft.C:375:60: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
       avgfractime += ((double)Global->transtimes[i])/Global->totaltimes[i];
                                                            ^
fft.C:384:9: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘starttime’
   Global->starttime = start;
         ^
fft.C:388:10: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘starttime’
    Global->starttime);
          ^
fft.C:390:10: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘initdonetime’
    Global->initdonetime);
          ^
fft.C:392:10: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘finishtime’
    Global->finishtime);
          ^
fft.C:394:10: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘finishtime’
    Global->finishtime-Global->starttime);
          ^
fft.C:394:29: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘starttime’
    Global->finishtime-Global->starttime);
                             ^
fft.C:396:10: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘finishtime’
    Global->finishtime-Global->initdonetime);
          ^
fft.C:396:29: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘initdonetime’
    Global->finishtime-Global->initdonetime);
                             ^
fft.C:400:38: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘finishtime’
          ((double) transtime)/(Global->finishtime-Global->initdonetime));
                                      ^
fft.C:400:57: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘initdonetime’
          ((double) transtime)/(Global->finishtime-Global->initdonetime));
                                                         ^
fft.C:415:3: error: ‘MAIN_END’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   MAIN_END;
   ^
fft.C:415:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
fft.C: In function ‘SlaveStart’:
fft.C:430:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘LOCK’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   LOCK(Global->idlock);
   ^
fft.C:430:14: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘idlock’
   LOCK(Global->idlock);
              ^
fft.C:431:19: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘id’
     MyNum = Global->id;
                   ^
fft.C:432:11: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘id’
     Global->id++;
           ^
fft.C:433:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘UNLOCK’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   UNLOCK(Global->idlock); 
   ^
fft.C:433:16: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘idlock’
   UNLOCK(Global->idlock); 
                ^
fft.C:435:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘BARINCLUDE’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   BARINCLUDE(Global->start);
   ^
fft.C:435:20: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARINCLUDE(Global->start);
                    ^
fft.C:440:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘BARRIER’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
   ^
fft.C:440:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:442:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   upriv = (double *) malloc(2*(rootN-1)*sizeof(double));  
   ^
fft.C:442:22: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
   upriv = (double *) malloc(2*(rootN-1)*sizeof(double));  
                      ^
fft.C:445:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
     exit(-1);
     ^
fft.C:456:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:477:11: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘transtimes’
     Global->transtimes[MyNum] = l_transtime;
           ^
fft.C:478:11: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘totaltimes’
     Global->totaltimes[MyNum] = finish-initdone;
           ^
fft.C:481:11: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘finishtime’
     Global->finishtime = finish;
           ^
fft.C:482:11: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘initdonetime’
     Global->initdonetime = initdone;
           ^
fft.C: In function ‘FFT1D’:
fft.C:603:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:623:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:643:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:657:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C:666:17: error: ‘struct GlobalMemory’ has no member named ‘start’
   BARRIER(Global->start, P);
                 ^
fft.C: In function ‘main’:
fft.C:416:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
../../Makefile.config:30: recipe for target 'fft.o' failed
make: *** [fft.o] Error 1
```